# matlab order of nested loops speed

Tags: matlab, performance, nested-loops

Suppose I have the following code. Will it be faster version 1 or version 2? What changes is the ordering of the two nested loops

VERSION 1

```
% bigArray has dim: [npolv,nz,nsv]
% npolv=68961 > nsv=200 > nz=81
for j=1:nz
   for qq=1:nsv
       % the output of fun is a vector dim npolv
       bigArray(:,j,qq) = fun();
   end
end
```

or VERSION 2

```
% bigArray has dim: [npolv,nz,nsv]
% npolv=68961 > nsv=200 > nz=81
for qq=1:nsv
    for j=1:nz
        % the output of fun is a vector with dim npolv
        bigArray(:,j,qq) = fun();
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't think there will be any noticeable difference but use tic & toc to measure it.

Comment: There *could* be a difference due to the ordering of the array in memory, but I agree with @JakobL that the only way to really tell is to measure it.

Comment: Actually, two is likely faster, but it depends on the size of the first dimension, and on the cost of `fun`. Measure, measure, measure.

Answer (score 1):

Version 2 would most probably be faster than version 1, due to the way that Matlab stores data in memory (column-wise, or more accurately the leftmost index changes fastest and stored in contiguous memory location) and the effects of memory caching (which fetches memory one page [e.g. 4 KB = 500 `double` elements] at a time). This is called *spatial locality*, or the *[locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)* principle. By looping over the rightmost index before a left one, we maximize the CPU cache efficiency since the CPU does not need to access the main memory (RAM) as often in order to fetch contiguous data items.

The effect is typically small to insignificant for small data matrices, but could be significant when the data size is larger than your platform's page size - in such cases you can see speedups of 2x or even more with version 2 compared to version 1.

Having said all this, if you could make your `fun()` vectorized, the potential speedups could be much larger than those of switching the loop order.

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate the vector `bigArray=zeros(DIM,nz,nsv)`, there is no practical difference.

In both cases, the function `fun()` is executed `nz*nsv` times, sequentially.

Instead, check the timing of each possibilities with `tic` `t=toc`, and with the use of `parfor` for Parallel Execution.